# How to enable nginx modules in docker image

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx config which starts as follows

```
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_set_misc_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_cache_purge_module.so;
```

When I use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:mainline

ADD config/ /etc/nginx/
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

I get the following error when I try to run the container:

```
2024/01/22 19:52:07 [emerg] 8#8: dlopen() "/etc/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so" failed (/etc/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
webserver  | nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/etc/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so" failed (/etc/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

So, the modules are not present. My question is, how can I enable them?
I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/954708/install-more-set-headers-in-nginx-1-15-8) post, which installs the modules as follows

```
$> sudo apt install software-properties-common
$> nginx=stable 
$> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/$nginx
$> sudo apt update
$> sudo apt dist-upgrade

$> sudo apt install nginx-extras
```

However, the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/$nginx` throws errors

```
17.78 Setting up packagekit-tools (1.2.6-5) ...
17.79 Setting up software-properties-common (0.99.30-4) ...
17.90 Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.10-1~deb12u1) ...
18.15 Traceback (most recent call last):
18.15   File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 362, in <module>
18.15     sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
18.15                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
18.15   File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 345, in main
18.15     shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
18.15                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
18.15   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
18.15     return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
18.15            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
18.15   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 86, in __init__
18.15     if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
18.15        ^^^^^^^^^^
18.15   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 126, in lpppa
18.15     self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
18.15                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
18.15   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 113, in lpteam
18.15     self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
18.15                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
18.15 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'
```

I'm a bit lost at this point on how to install the nginx modules?

Comment: "I found this post," - which describes how to implement this on a normal host. Not a docker instance. Upgrading/patching an existing instance is not how docker was intended to be managed. You should be changing your dockerfile.

Comment: Hi @symcbean, you did not link the post!

Comment: I was quoting you.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we search for that error message (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'`), we find as the first result [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480616/adding-opencpn-repository-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute). The top voted answer suggests that the solution is:

```
apt-get install python3-launchpadlib
```

And indeed, that lets us run `add-apt-repository`:

```
$ podman run -it --rm docker.io/nginx:mainline bash
root@744ec39923cd:/# apt update >& /dev/null
root@744ec39923cd:/# apt -y install software-properties-common >& /dev/null
root@744ec39923cd:/# add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  .
  .
  .
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 113, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'people'
root@744ec39923cd:/# apt -y install python3-launchpadlib >& /dev/null
root@744ec39923cd:/# add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/ bookworm main'
Description:
This PPA contains the latest Stable Release version of the nginx web server software.

**Only Non-End-of-Life Ubuntu Releases are supported in this PPA**

**Development releases of Ubuntu are not officially supported by this PPA, and uploads for those will not be available until actual final releases for those versions**
More info: https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-ubuntu-stable-bookworm.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-ubuntu-stable-bookworm.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nginx-ubuntu-stable.gpg with fingerprint 8B3981E7A6852F782CC4951600A6F0A3C300EE8C
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4492 kB]
Fetched 4492 kB in 1s (4458 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

But that ultimately fails, because the [referenced ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Enginx/+archive/ubuntu/stable) only has packages for Ubuntu; there are no packages for the Debian Bookworm based image used by the `nginx:stable` image.

Furthermore, that PPA only supports Ubuntu versions up to Bionic (18.04), which was released in 2018.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741684/147356) has instructions for extending the base image with the nginx dynamic modules.

Depending on your needs, it may be simpler to start with a recent Ubuntu-based image. Nginx and most of the modules are already packaged for Ubuntu, so something like this would get you most of the way there:

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04

RUN apt update && apt -y install \
  nginx \
  libnginx-mod-http-ndk \
  libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter \
  libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge \
  && \
  apt clean all
```

That gets you everything except `ngx_http_set_misc_module.so`.